# How to configure an AWS SQS message listener with Resin web application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-sqs, resin

Currently I'm working on a Java web application which runs on Resin 4.0.55 and I am new to working with AWS SQS.

I need to implement a SQS message listener (JMS message listener as consumer) for my resin application. The listener should listen to the SQS FIFO queue and once a message appear on the queue, the web application should receive the message.

Currently I'm referring following AWS documentations:

[Getting Started with the Amazon SQS Java Messaging Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/getting-started.html)
[Working Java Example for Using JMS with Amazon SQS Standard Queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/code-examples.html)

Please kindly help me to implement a listener for Java application in Resin server.